# How to calculate Centroid at DTWCLUST library in R

Tags: r, cluster-computing

I'm using DTWCLUST package in r. Here's my code.

```
library(dtwclust)
sc1 <- read.table("D:/handling data/confirm4.csv", header=T, sep="," )
hc_sbd <- dtwclust(sc1, type = 'h', k=5L, method = 'ward.D', preproc = zscore,
                distance = 'dtw', control = list(trace=TRUE) )
clusters <- cutree(hc_sbd,6)
head(clusters)
result <- cbind.data.frame(sc1,clusters)
plot(hc_sbd, type='centroids', clus=1) + ylim(-3, 3) + scale_x_continuous( breaks = c(1,6,12,18,24,30,36,42), labels= real_label )
```

When I ran `plot(hc_sbd, type='centroids', clus=1) + ylim(-3, 3) + scale_x_continuous( breaks = c(1,6,12,18,24,30,36,42), labels= real_label )`, prototype was plotted.
But I don't know how the centroids is calculated by PAM, which is default options. Can anyone help me understand the concept of PAM to obtaion centroids?? 
Thanks for in advance.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-medoids

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about innards of the algorithm but not it's implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the implementation included in the package,
*k* series from the data are randomly chosen as initial centroids.
Then the distance between all series and the centroids is calculated
(or retrieved from the whole distance matrix if it was precomputed),
and each series is assigned to the cluster of its nearest centroid.
For each created cluster,
the distance between all member series is computed (if necessary),
and the series with minimum sum of distances is chosen as the new centroid.
This continues iteratively until no series change clusters,
or the maximum number of allowed iterations has been exceeded.

[Here's the code](https://github.com/asardaes/dtwclust/blob/master/R/CENTROIDS-pam.R).

(You should be using the `tsclust` function if you're using dtwclust version 4.0.0 or above)

Comment: Excellent!! Thanks~~ You are great guy~